# Is it ok to cast a STL container with Base type to Derived type?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, polymorphism

Is it ok to cast a STL container from Base type to Derived type ? 
For example, I have two vectors. First one is in type of a Base class, second is in type of a Derive class.

```
class Base
{
// Code
};

class Derive : public Base
{
// Code
};
```

Usage

```
    vector<Base*>*  vec_base = new vector<Base*>;

    // Add some Derive type data to vec_base

    vector<Derive*>* vec_derive = (vector<Derive*>*)(vec_base);

    // Using elements as Derive pointers. Works fine.
```

Is this ok ? (It works fine, but I wanted to get some comments about this). Thank you very much.

EDIT: Updating according to the answers.

Say, If I use that vector carefully, and will not use with multiple-inheritance and will not insert objects other than Derive type, is it ok ? (I guess, it is not)

And thank you very much for the answers.

Comment: Re: update - nothing you can do without using something like std::transform will make it use any cast other than reinterpret_cast, which is not what you're looking for

Comment: @awoodland So, reinterpret_cast is bad even If it not polymophic types ? I mean, even if I 100% sure that "I know the exact type" of the vector reinterpret_cast is undefined for this case ?

Comment: reinterpret_cast is definitely bad on std::vector, the problem is that there's no (portable, standardised) reason to assume that the memory layout for std::vector<Base*> and std::vector<Derrive*> are compatible such that this would work.

Comment: @awoodland, both are pointers, pointers behave equally no matter what they are pointing to, and pointers occupy the same size no matter what they are pointing to... If we suppose that the vector implementation is not specialized for Base* or Derive*, and the it is no intrusive, the solution will work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is definitely not ok, and is one of the examples of c-style casts masking errors. "It works for me" is not indicative of well defined behaviour in this instance.

If you really want to do this I'd suggest:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
// Code
virtual ~Base();
};

class Derrive : public Base
{
// Code
};

Derrive *convert(Base * in) {
   // assert here?
   return dynamic_cast<Derrive*>(in);
}

int main() {
    vector<Base*>*  vec_base = new vector<Base*>;

    // Add some Derrive type data to vec_base

    vector<Derrive*>* vec_derrive = new vector<Derrive*>;

    transform(vec_base->begin(), vec_base->end(), back_insert_iterator<vector<Derrive*> >(*vec_derrive), convert);
}
```

Comment: That is nice way of doing it. Thank you very much

Comment: It's a shame dynamic_cast isn't a function because then you would potentially not need the convert function to wrap dynamic_cast at all.

Comment: When you use the vec_derrive, check each member for null before you use it.  If any of the dynamic_casts fail, you'll get null entries in your vector.

Comment: If you are certain that all the elements are in fact pointers to `Derive`, you can legitimately replace `dynamic_cast` with `static_cast`, which will be faster.  Of course, if that turns out not to be the case, your program will exhibit Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: With lambda functions from C++11 I'd be tempted to move the cast into a lambda function to remove the need for the `convert()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a c-style cast, which is essentially doing a `reinterpret_cast`, which tells the compiler "treat x like y from now on, and just trust me that it works".  So it will definitely compile, but is a bad idea.  There is no type safety here, and it may work some of the time, but will crash unpredictably at other times.

What you can do instead:

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i < vec_base->length(); i++)
{
  Derrive* d = dynamic_cast<Derrive*> (vec_base[i]);
  if (d ) {
     // this element is a Derrive instance, so we can treat it like one here
  }
  // else, skip it, log an error, throw an exception, whatever,
  // this element in the vector is not of type Derrive
}
```

Comment: Yeah, It should be the way. But I can't let users to use dynamic_cast, since it is in the critical path. I thought, by forcing the compiler to cast to Derrive type, it should work

Answer (score 1):

This is not ok. Templated types with different `T`s are unrelated types (even though they both say `std::vector`, and using a C-style cast just lets you get away with undefined behavior.

If it seems to work for now, consider yourself unlucky that it didn't crash.

If you know that ALL the items in the vector are the derived class then just make the vector point to derived objects up front. If you don't know that, then the cast isn't safe.

Answer (score 0):

No. That won't work well.

Say I have `Derrive2` that derives from `Base`. I can put that in the STL container, but it won't safely cast to `Derrive`.

Comment: Ok, say I will use that vector carefully and wont put Derrived2 type to vector. Now, is it ok ?

Comment: @Morpheus No it's not ok - the vector types still aren't related.

Comment: I almost +1'd @Morpheus for the roar of laughter that came out of my mouth a minute or so ago.

Answer (score 0):

The safer way to do this is using std::transform.

But, since inside the implementation of std::list, T=Base* or T=Derived* behaves the same way (both have the same size), a list has same inner structure than a list. So it is possible to do the following trick:

```
vector<Derived*> vector2 = *( reinterpret_cast< vector<Derived*>* >(&vector1) );
```

Note:
My answer is informational, please stick with the std::transform approach. I am not sure if in STDC++ implementation others than GCC's the vector behave the same way, ie. I am not sure if the assertion "list< Base* > and list< Derivated*> have the same inner structure" is true in others implementations.