# Casting containers C++

Tags: c++, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it ok to cast a STL container with Base type to Derived type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460371/is-it-ok-to-cast-a-stl-container-with-base-type-to-derived-type)

This should be a quick question... If I have a container, say an STL list, of a base class, is it possible to casts the entire container to a type of subclass? E.g.

```
[A inherits from base class B]

list<B*> list1;
list1.push_back(new A());

list<A*> list2 = list1;
```

The compiler is complaining: "`conversion from std::vector<B*, std:allocator<B*> >' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<Bar*, ...>' requested.`"

Is this possible, or am I'm just screwing it up?

Comment: This is the same question, I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460371/is-it-ok-to-cast-a-stl-container-with-base-type-to-derived-type

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I hadn't come across that post before submitting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `std::list<T>` and `std::list<U>` are completely different, incompatible types, if `std::is_same<T,U>::value` is `false`, i.e if the type arguments `T` and `U` aren't same.

Use `std::transform` and do appropriate casting in the callback.

Comment: This won't be (generally) safe because the OP is assigning from a parent class to child class pointer.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't directly possible because `list`s with different template types are completely unrelated containers.

If you *know* that all the items in `list1` are actually the child class `A` then just make `list1` contain them as such up front. If you *don't* know that they're all of the child class then the conversion you want to do is illegal.

What are you *really* trying to do here?

Comment: I agree with your second statement. What I'm really trying to do is have a template function that receives a type, say a subclass, and populates a list of that parametrized type. However, there can obviously be only 1 return type, so it would return list<B> where B is the base class. Thus, the client calls Foo::createGrid<A>(..), and would like to expect a list<A> returned, but he gets back a list<B> and would like to cast it to list<A>. No worries anyway, I found a workaround, but it was something I wanted to look into in regards to casting STL containers.

Answer (score 1):

The safer way to do this is using std::transform.

But, since inside the implementation of std::list, T=A* or T=B* behaves the same way (both have the same size), a list has same inner structure than a list. So it is possible to do the following trick:

```
list<B*> list2 = *( reinterpret_cast< list<B*>* >(&list1) );
```

Note:
My answer is informational, please stick with the std::transform approach. Also, I tested this with GCC and it works, but I am not sure if in others STDC++ implementation the list behave the same way.

Comment: +1 for this highly unsafe but usually (under some constraints) working idea.