# Cast derived class list to base class list in C++

Tags: c++, containers, reinterpret-cast, stdlist

Is it safe to use `reinterpret_cast` to convert `std::list<Derived *>` to `std::list<Base *>`?

```cpp
class Base {
    ...
}

class Derived : public Base{
    ...
}

void func(const std::list<Base *> &list);

int main() {
    std::list<Derived *> list1;

    // ...

    func(*reinterpret_cast<std::list<Base *> *>(&list1)); // Safe ?
}
```

If it's a safe cast, we don't need to copy the list, which may improve performance.

Comment: Are the classes polymorphic? If they are, why don't you have a list of pointer to the *base* class instead?

Comment: Also, the "standard" container should almost *always* be `std::vector`. What is the use-case for a `std::list` in your program?

Comment: As a third point, if your function doesn't modify the container itself, then consider the standard-library way to pass containers: Through a range using iterators.

Comment: The classes are polymorphic. I know the std::vector is safe due to the sequencial memory layout, it's just an example. I want to know if it's safe for all template containers such as std::map, std::unordered_map, QList, QMap, QHash...

Comment: A `list<T*>` is NOT a `list<U*>` even if `T` and `U` are related.
What you want is a `dynamic_cast` on the **elements** of the list.

Comment: Why do you even have a list of derived objects? It is more common to have a list of Base and access the derived objects only through overriden virtual functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it ok to cast a STL container with Base type to Derived type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460371/is-it-ok-to-cast-a-stl-container-with-base-type-to-derived-type)

Comment: No, you can't safely "cast" a `std::list<Derived *> &` to a `std::list<Base *> &`.   If `Base` is polymorphic then, instead of creating a `std::list<Derived *>`, create a `std::list<Base *>`.   If the `std::list<Derived *>` is created by some other code you can't control, then do the conversion/copying once, and use `std::list<Base *>` from there.  Same goes if the container is `std::vector` instead of `std::list`.  [If you still need to convert any of the `Base *` elements to `Derived *`, then fix your design of `Base`].

Answer (score 7):

This code has **undefined behavior** regardless of the container template: `std::list<Base*>` and `std::list<Derived*>` are **unrelated** types.  Even `std::vector<int*>` and `std::vector<const int*>` are unrelated.

One reason for this is that allowing these conversions would allow `reinterpret_cast<std::list<Base*>&>(derived_list).push_front(base_ptr)` to add a pointer of the **wrong** type.  For the same reason, `char**` cannot be implicitly converted to `const char**`; unfortunately the `const char* const*` conversion that *is* allowed has no **analog** for container types.  The C++ type system just isn’t that powerful.

It’s true that obvious implementations will do what you expect for casts like this because the layouts are all the same, but non-obvious implementations may “misbehave” arbitrarily for code like this.  The real answer is to make `func` accept a **range** rather than a specific container type, which makes it work with `std::list<Derived*>`, `std::vector<Base*>`, and probably `std::generator<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` as well.

Comment: Making `func` accept a `std::range` basically makes it a template and that's what the original poster probably wanted to avoid.

Comment: @KaiPetzke: It definitely makes it a template, which is the correct way to handle multiple types in a similar fashion.  I don’t know if the asker wants to avoid templates or not; we do wish we had _more_ well-defined options for cases like this, as I already said.

Comment: Yes, more flexible casting of containers of derived classes to at least read-only containers of base classes would be a big win. For some other types, namely `std::shared_ptr<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<T>`, the ability to cast is explicitly implemented in the definition of those types, but those cases are rare in the C++ standard library.

Comment: @KaiPetzke: They’re rare but not happenstance: the conversions create a _new_ object related to the original, which is efficient only because they contain only a pointer.  You could similarly have a `list_view<T>` that allowed certain conversions, but then you have to manage ownership separately.

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong. Even if you could reinterpret cast a `Derived*` to a `Base*`, you cannot reinterpret cast a `std::list<Derived*>` to a `std::list<Base*>` in a meaningful, portable way. They are two unrelated types. Being instantiations of the same template does not impose any relation between them, other than being instantiations of the same template.

`reinterpret_cast` is often misunderstood as an any-to-any cast, but thats not what it is. Actually it has a rather limited set of valid use cases. For a complete list see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast. Casting a `std::list<Derived*>` to a `std::list<Base*>` is not among them.

---

Probably you do not have to copy the list in the first place. If the types are polymorphic then no copy nor cast is needed, you can use the `std::list<Base*>` and the elements virtual methods. If however you do need to cast a `Derived*` to a `Base*` then you can cast the elements via `dynamic_cast` without casting the whole list. Also no copy needed.

Comment: Related question to your answer: Since a `Derived*` is always a `Base*`, does that mean you could also do a `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`? Not that I would recommend that, I would still prefer to see `dynamic_cast` for polymorphic types for RTTI

Comment: @HarryP2023: Derived-to-base conversions are implicit: you use `static_cast` when you need a derived version of a base pointer that you already know somehow points to an object of the derived type.  `dynamic_cast` can do upcasts, but using it to do that, outside perhaps of certain generic-programming contexts, merely illustrates and/or causes confusion.